# Issue with a mobile menu

Tags: mobile, menu

I have a problem displaying the mobile menu. Here is the page http://www.hawaiiluaus.com/contact.htm
When you minimize the screen you can see the menu showing up very little bit, indicating it must be some sort of z-index issues. I tried a few solutions but it still did not work. I would appreciate any tips for this issue. thanks!

Comment: Looks like there's nothing in the menu. Want to elaborate on what your problem is and maybe give us some code to work with?

Comment: Thanks I was able to fix it. There was overflow: hidden issues in the code that made the problem with the mobile menu.